# Can a Variable be stored in an Excel File that can not be accessed through Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I just discovered that in MS Word it is possible to store a Variable in a MS Word File that can not be accessed through the regular interface when running Microsoft Word.

```
Sub SetMyVariable()
Dim VARNAME As String
    VARNAME = "HiddenVar"
    ActiveDocument.Variables.Add VARNAME, "My special info"
End Sub
```

This gets saved in the XML Schema under `word\settings.xml`

I have tried using the `ThisWorkbook` Object in Excel, but it doesn't seem to have a `Variable` object that can be added like in word.

I want to know if there is something similar in Excel to store information/varialbes that get saved with the file.

PS: the closest thing I can think of (and use in codig) is a hidden named range.

Comment: Try `CustomDocumentProperties`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863250/how-to-add-a-documentproperty-to-customdocumentproperties-in-excel

Comment: I'm aware of this option, but a regular user can still access this and change it... although I realize that the vast majority will never bother to look. the Variable object in Word is like a data island, in that it can not be changed without specifically knowing it is there or looking at the XML file, which i found interesting.

Comment: AFAIK, hidden names are used in Excel instead of .Variables http://excelsemipro.com/2010/11/hide-or-show-names-in-excel-with-vba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the [`CustomXMLParts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863162.aspx) property of the `Workbook` which from the link seems a generic feature of Office products and available in Excel. Given you noted that a user would have to manually inspect the XML within the unzipped xlsx files then this seems to map to the Word `Variables` feature. The code sample just substitutes `ThisWorkbook` for `ActiveDocument`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TextXMLPart()

    Dim objXMLPart As CustomXMLPart

    'add
    Set objXMLPart = ThisWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add("<foo>bar</foo>")

    'inspect
    For Each objXMLPart In ThisWorkbook.CustomXMLParts
        Debug.Print objXMLPart.XML
    Next objXMLPart

End Sub
```

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567921/how-can-i-persist-data-for-an-excel-ribbon-addin-in-excel) (which focuses on Excel and [vsto](/questions/tagged/vsto)) states that:

> Custom XML parts For an application-level add in, this is my preferred method of storing any application data that needs to be persisted in a saved xls file without ever being visible to the user.

Comment: This is exactely what I was looking for! Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.